# Yammer REST endpoint to get user by full name

Tags: yammer

I'm working on a migration Product that migrates data in to yammer. I want to match the user on source to user on target based on full name. How do I retrieve user from Yammer based on Full Name? There is one REST endpoint to get user by email. Is there something similar to this for user Full Name ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this with the User API as it only supports getting a user by ID or email. You might want to look at the [Autocomplete API](https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-autocomplete), but it might be quicker to use the [Data Export API](https://about.yammer.com/success/activate/admin-guide/monitoring-your-data/export-data/) and find the user in the users.csv file. It's hard to provide recommendations when you don't explain what you app does.

Comment: I'm working on a migration Product that migrates data in to yammer. I want to match the user on source to user on target based on full name. How do I retrieve user from Yammer based on Full Name?

Comment: Look at the autocomplete api documentation.